# Передача параметров на другую страницу

Tags: django

уважаемые форумчане!

Имеется страница с таблицей иностранных слов:

```
<tbody>
   {% for word in word_list %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td>{{word.russian_word}}</td>
        <td>{{word.foreign_word}}</td>
        <td>{{word.context}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'edit' %}?id={{word.id}}" class="btn btn-success">Редактировать</a>
    </tr>            
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Соответственно страница с иностранным словом находится по адресу: "/edit/?id=21".

Есть еще вариант с передачей параметра через строку запроса "/edit/21".

Отсюда два вопроса:

1. какая принципиальная разница между "/edit/?id=21" и "/edit/21". Какой способ предпочтительнее использовать в данном случае?
2. это нормальная практика светить id записи?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. /edit/?id=21 - передаётся как GET параметр, а в /edit/21 - 21 это часть самой ссылки, лично я бы использовал второй вариант. Но решать вам, как вам будет удобнее реализовать и как вы это видите.
2. Да, конечно, что такого в том чтобы засветить id записи? Конечно, если это не конфиденциальная информация, как например: номер карты или номер транзакции.

Comment: Я понимаю, что это разные способы передачи. Но не очень поняла, когда какой нужно использовать. Почему вы бы выбрали второй способ?

Comment: Да, это разные способы передачи. Я выбрал второй, потому что он будет более лёгким в воспроизведении для пользователя. Использовать можно любой, разницы между ними никакой, кроме способа реализации.